# How do I figure out the optimal number of parallel downloads with mult_curl?

Tags: php, curl

I run a crawler that continually downloads a bunch of websites. Bandwidth is not an issue. Is there a standard maximum for parallel downloads? Or a way to figure how many urls I can download without threatening server uptime?

EDIT: I'm referring to resource usage on my server. The download list is designed to ease load on remote servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers perform 2-5 parallel requests per server. That's a pretty reasonable range but go with 2 if you really want to be safe. Ultimately the effect on the server depends on too many variables (server speed, memory, bandwidth, dynamic code, requests per second, ...) to give a precise answer.

UPDATE: Thanks for clarifying the question. I don't think anybody can give you an answer. Assuming you really had near unlimited bandwidth the number of factors determining your safe load are still massively variable. You haven't even discussed what your script does with the downloaded content. If it saves straight to disk your limit will be somewhere in your IO system and the performance of that depends on all the things I mentioned above. As it is your question can't be answered and if it could it would belong on ServerFault as it is really a question about optimising and monitoring IO load.

Short answer though: No, there is no formal or informal standard for maximum downloads in regards to the client machine and the only way to figure it out would be to try different limits and monitor the load.

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question.

Comment: then you question isn't as clear as you think it is. You're asking what the 'standard maximum for parallel downloads' is. I just told you. That fact you're using mult_curl is irrelevent. Perhaps you need to clarify wether you're talking about your server or theirs. In general you'll bring down their server long before you bring down your own, especially if the content is dynamically generated.

Comment: It's irrelevant because browser limits are implemented to optimize resources on the client and not the server. But you're right in that I need to clarify whether I'm referring to my server on the remote servers. I'll update the question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question but you are wrong about the browser limits. They are designed to prevent harm to remote servers. There are numerous discussions on the issue on numerous browser mailing lists. The limits tend to be very conservative but they are definitely not there to protect the browser (you can parallel download many more files if the remote domains are different - which is one reason why some larger sites provide resources on subdomains like static.domain.com, static2.domain.com, etc.)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yahoo's research team ran a comprehensive test on the issue, interesting read: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/ - "One possible contributor for slower response times is the amount of CPU thrashing on the client caused by increasing the number of parallel downloads. The more images that are downloaded in parallel, the greater the amount of CPU thrashing on the client. On my laptop at work, the CPU jumped from 25% usage for 2 parallel downloads to 40% usage for 20 parallel downloads. These values can vary significantly across [computers]"